# How to load local dataset (X, y) using Keras framework

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dataset, conv-neural-network

I have a local dataset devised to trainingSet and testSet folders, and each one contain 3 classes, like this:

```
-Training_Set
   --Class1
     --img1.jpg
     --img2.jpg
     ..
   --Class2
     --img101.jpg
     --img102.jpg
     ..
   --Class3
     --img201.jpg
     --img202.jpg

-Test_Set
       --Class1
         --img10.jpg
         --img11.jpg
         ..
       --Class2
         --img150.jpg
         --img140.jpg
         ..
       --Class3
         --img210.jpg
         --img220.jpg
```

and i want to load it like we load the Cifar dataset:

```
(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (although not sure why you want it exactly like cifar):

```
import cv2  # pip install opencv-python
import numpy as np
import os


class ImageLoader:
    """Load images in arrays without batches."""

    def __init__(self, train_dir, test_dir):
        """Create class."""
        self.train_dir = train_dir
        self.test_dir = test_dir

    def load_data(self):
        """Load the data."""
        features, labels = [], []

        for source in [self.train_dir, self.test_dir]:
            input, output = [], []
            for class_name in os.listdir(source):
                if os.path.isdir(class_name):
                    for img_name in os.listdir(class_name):
                        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(self.train_dir, class_name, img_name))

                        # ...
                        # Modify your image array here.
                        # ...

                        input.append(img)
                        output.append(class_name)  # or other method to convert label

            # Shuffle labels.
            combine = list(zip(input, output))  # zip as list for Python 3
            np.random.shuffle(combine)
            input, output = zip(*combine)
            features.append(input)
            labels.append(output)

        return [[np.array(features[0], dtype=np.float32),
                 np.array(labels[0], dtype=np.float32)],
                [np.array(features[1], dtype=np.float32),
                 np.array(labels[1], dtype=np.float32)]]


cifar10 = ImageLoader('path-to-training', 'path-to-testing')
(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Comment: i need it like Cifar because i want to apply a code that i found on github:
https://github.com/titu1994/DenseNet/blob/master/cifar10.py

Comment: The code is not working for Python3, and for the Python2.7 i get this error:
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: What do you mean "not working for Python3"? And on which line do you get the ValueError?

Comment: For Python3 i got error on zip function, for te error i got it n this line:      input, output = zip(*combine)

Comment: I added this bit (`combine = list(zip(input, output))`) for Python 3 and this will work for you. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Well, you need to have the lists populated. It [works](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/19AB).

Comment: Your error clearly states you need more that 0 values to unpack. It is not populated.

Comment: what do you mean by populated ?

Comment: Have you populated the list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`image-dataset-loader`](https://github.com/soroushj/image-dataset-loader) to load your dataset:

```sh
pip install image-dataset-loader
```

```py
from image_dataset_loader import load

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load('/path/to/your/dataset', ['Training_Set', 'Test_Set'])
```

Also, you can use Keras's `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` instead. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) and [the docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Comment: i know this method, but there is two problems, it use batch and the X, y are mixed.
and i want to load it like we load the Cifar dataset:
```
(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()
```

Comment: @Adelov I published a little utility function on GitHub that does what you need. Updated the answer with the link to the repo and an example. See the repo for more details.